# power shell script to exclude onedrive folder

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

power shell script to exclude onedrive folder

```
# Define the root folder to scan
$rootFolder = "C:\Users"

# Get all files in the root folder and its subdirectories, excluding OneDrive folder
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -File -Recurse -Exclude "OneDrive", "OneDrive - *"

# Display the list of files
if ($files.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "No files found in the user folders."
} else {
    Write-Host "List of files in user folders:"
    foreach ($file in $files) {
        Write-Host $file.FullName
    }
}

# Optionally, display the total number of files found
$totalFiles = $files.Count
Write-Host "Total files found: $totalFiles"
```

but this is not working kindly help anyone

But this script is not working. Kindly, help anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would feel safer doing it like this, rather than excluding a string on the get-childitem:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users' -File -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Fullname -notmatch '^C:\\Users\\[^\\]+\\OneDrive'}
```

if you want to also exclude the Public user, you can use this instead:

```
$Items = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users' -File -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Fullname -notmatch '^C:\\Users\\[^\\]+\\OneDrive|^C:\\Users\\Public'}
```

That way you are specifically asking it to filter out the OneDrive folder in that specific place, so if for whatever reason a user created a folder called OneDrive somewhere else (and its not actually OneDrive, just a folder called OneDrive),then it wouldn't exclude it.